# Fetch user details from Active Directory

Tags: java, mysql, windows-server-2008

I am using Microsoft Windows Server 2008 and I want to fetch the details of the users from the Active Directory and only get that users logged into a particular web application. (contains *.java files).

I got Active Directory already installed into my system.
I tried to configure System DSN (ODBC Connection) but got no luck.

In other words, when the user will login through his/her username or password, the verification process will take through Active Directory fetching from My Sql database.

I have also got MySql installed, but when I am trying to configure System DSN or User DSN, I got no option to point that MySql, it shows all options except MySql.

[image]

Please tell me, how to configure active directory database as mysql?
Thanks in Advance!!
Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

To be able to connect to a MySQL DB instance, you would need to have a MySQL connector installed on the machine you are trying to connect from.

This can be downloaded from the MySQL website: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html

Once this is installed, you can select MySQL from the system DSN and user DSN.